# How to keep one side of the border square when changing the width?

Tags: html, css

I wanted to change the `border-left` propertie in `css` but it doesn't give me a nice rectangle like I expected.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
input[type=text] {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-left: 100px solid red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Text field with only a left border:</p>

<form>
  <label for="fname">First Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

When running this code, you can see that the red box doesn't have perfect straight lines.

Do you guys know a solution to this problem ?

Thanks !

Comment: which type border you need

Comment: You expect the red border to be a rectangle, someone else might expect the black borders to be rectangles. The implementors had to compromise.

Comment: whats your problem? not clear

Comment: To whose who're not certain about the problem: change all the borders to 100px width. The four borders will then all be trapeziums. The OP is asking how to make one of those borders a rectangle.

Comment: bcause you define `border-left:100px` thats why

Comment: which type of output you need clear first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increase the left padding and use an inset `box-shadow`

```css
input[type=text] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  padding-left: 120px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-shadow: inset 100px 0 0 0 red;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="fname">First Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem: the borders are trapezium-shaped. You can see this by making all the borders, say, 40px thick.

```css
div {
  width:100px; height:100px;
  border:40px solid;
  border-color:black red;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

(Note: making the right border red as well, to show the shapes better.)

One possible solution is to draw an overlay on top of the left border, in the form of an absolutely positioned pseudo-element.

```css
div {
  width:100px; height:100px;
  border:40px solid;
  border-color:black red;
  position:relative;
}

div::before {
  display:block; content:'';
  position:absolute;
  top:-40px; left:-40px; width:0; height:calc(100px + 40px + 40px);
  border-left:inherit;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

I'm sure there will be more elegant methods. If so, I will upvote.